# Elasticsearch.service failed after enable elasticsearch security features

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I follow the this link [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elastic-stack-on-centos-7](http://%5Bhttps://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elastic-stack-on-centos-7%5D) to setup elasticsearch in my RH linux server.

Elasticsearch.service is running well without `xpack.security.enabled: true` in my elasticsearch.yml.
But service fail when `xpack.security.enabled: true` is implemented in elasticsearch.yml

[image]

Comment: your error message is not clear, can you provide relevant error logs?

Comment: Hi, Opster. I already use -l command to list all the logs for this service. Maybe you have any suggestion command to list more log for my elasticsearch.service? Thank you

Comment: Hi Opster. I had solved the problem by enabling single-node discovery. Thanks for your help.